# Can't enable CORS on Angular and Jboss application

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, jboss, cors

i have an application server on Jboss and i created the frontend with Angular. For testing i'm using this command on windows run to open a new chrome window without security

**chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C://Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security**

If i open a regular chrome window i get this error:

[image]

I looked up for some guides and all i found is to create a new **proxy.conf.json** with this code inside:

```
{
  "/api/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:8080",
      "secure": false,
      "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

After this i had to add some code to the **angular.json** like this :

```
"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "o365calendar-frontend:build:build",
            "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
            },
```

This is the service i'm using for the calls to the backend:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class SpringbootService {

  private url: string;
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    // This will now refer to http://localhost:4200/o365calendar-web
    this.url = '/o365calendar-web/rest';
  }

  getUtenti(){
    return this.http.get(this.url + '/members')
  }

  getEventi(email: string){
    return this.http.get(this.url + '/calendarevents/' + email)
  }

  postUtente(body: {}){
    return this.http.post(this.url + '/members', body)

  }
}
```

This is my app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import {HomeComponent} from "./components/home/home.component";
import {CalendarComponent} from "./components/calendar/calendar.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", component: HomeComponent },
  { path: "calendar/:email", component: CalendarComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

The work should be done but when i use the **ng serve** the problem is still there. Did i miss something?

Ps: The home page of jboss is on " http://localhost:8080/o365calendar-web/index.jsf "

Comment: When you configure the Angular proxy, you have to call your API through the Angular proxy (so call `http://localhost:4200/api/...`). Can you show us the code you use to call your API in Angular?

Comment: @g00glen00b do you mean the service i use for the backend calls ? In that case this is it:

https://i.gyazo.com/4aa5f4fcd0e247da1a7d20bdf6cca64a.png

Comment: can you add that code to your question? It makes it easier to copy-paste it into an answer or for people to try it out by themselves.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)